# Spring RestTemplate throws IllegalArgumentException: not a valid HTTP URL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   [https://localhost/pcap/search?stime=20110930%2E000000&etime=20110930%2E235959&bpf=tcp

Here is the call I made using Spring RestFul Template:

```java
final PcapSearchResponse pcapSearchResult = restTemplate.postForObject(
    nPulseApiUris.get(2), null, PcapSearchResponse.class, sTime, eTime, bpf);
```

I don't understand why that is a bad URL? I used UTF-8 to encode the "." character but I am not sure why my URL is still invalid.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of `RestTemplate` mentions that:

> Furthermore, the String-argument methods assume that the URL String is unencoded.

So, when passing your URL as string, don't encode it. Spring will take care of that.

Comment: Hi Bozho, thank you very much for your response. Yes I did not encode the url. The URL looks like the following in my code in which the nPulseApiUris is of type List<String>:
`https://localhost/pcap/search?stime={stime}&amp;etime=${etime}&amp;bpf=${bpf}`

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Bozho, I greatly appreciate your response.

My request parameters which I am trying to post to the RESTful service URI `https://localhost/pcap/search`are:

`stime=20110930.000000 etime=20110930.235959 bpf=tcp`

Thank you so much Bozho!

Comment: Looks ok. Now get rid rid of amp

Comment: If I get rid of the ampersand, I'm not sure how I'm going to post those parameters to the RESTful service URI. Hence I thought if I append it, that would work.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Don't remove the whole amperasnd, but don't write it encoded. So `&` instead of `&amp;`

Comment: Hi @Bozho: When I did that, Spring throws an exception state that it does not recognize that character as a valid character.

Comment: for the record - can you try without any ampersands and see if the problem persists (i.e. assume the url is ../foo/bar rather than ..?a=foo&b=bar

Comment: Hi @Bozho: Yes tried that before and I get an exception saying that it doesn't recognize the & character.

Comment: if you don't have an ampersand, it tells you it can't recognize it?

Comment: If I don't have &amp; instead of &, Spring complains and says it cannot recognize &.

Comment: how does it complain and when? exception?

Comment: yes it complains with an exception saying that it doesn't recognize the & character in the URL.

Comment: In my case, there was a space before the url, it was coming from some property, and that was causing the issue :(